# Interpreting SCHEME for SICP

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I have read through a bunch of Structures and Interpretations of Computer Programs and it has really captured me. I love they way it explains programming concepts. But the problem is that I don't know how to get MIT Scheme working. I don't know much about how to quickly interpret/compile in languages that require a compiler/interpreter. (doing it in JavaScript is incredibly easy) I have tried DrRacket but would love  to use sublime text then quickly run it.

I have downloaded the official MIT-SCHEME bundle but I have no idea on how to get it actually working after 3 hours.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: @ubadub windows 7

Comment: Try [racket](https://racket-lang.org/download/)

Comment: Have you read through the documentation on running MIT Scheme on Windows?

Comment: I wish I could say "just do X and you'll be fine", but I installed MIT Scheme and it looks like their Windows install is broken. It's probably possible to fix it with some manual labour, but I'll stick to Racket.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be familiar with the `sicp` package for Racket that allows you to write programs in a `#lang sicp` language. If you're interested in running them from the command line a la Javascript, that's certainly possible; if you run

racket

on a file that starts with `#lang sicp` (and you have the sicp package installed), it should run fine at the command line. It should be easy to bind this to a sublime command.

HTH